# About compare two index : (a,b) and (a)

Tags: mysql, indexing

Table t have two columns

```
a varchr(50) not null
b varchr(50) not null
```

and could have below search scenarios

- search only specify a (e.g `foo1,foo2,...`) (`select a,b,status,count(*) where a in (xxx) group by a,b,status` )
- search only specify b(e.g. `bar1,bar2,...`) (`select a,b,status,count(*) where b in (xxx) group by a,b,status` )
- a and b both specify (`select a,b,status,count(*) where a in (xxx) and b in (xxx) group by a,b,status` )

Naturally should create index for a and b, e.g.

```
alter table t add key idx_a_b (a,b);
alter table t add key idx_b (b);
```

but now I wonder if above index has any difference with below index

```
alter table t add key idx_a (a);
alter table t add key idx_b (b);
```

I think if has any difference it maybe could ignore. Am I right?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the first example will be used whenever you only query for a or when you query for a and b. So it would be slightly more efficient as you only need two indexes instead of 3, but the difference should be negligible. Maybe try both and do some explains and profiling.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal indexes are on `(a, b, status)` and `(b, status)`.

These cover all three queries, meaning that all the column in the query are in the indexes.  These are also optimal for the first two queries.

The third is problematic because of the two `in` clauses.  There is no index (in MySQL) that handles the filtering.